# Получение ответа от обработчика формы, посланной AJAX, в виде переменных или массива

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$('#order_form').submit(function(){
    $.post(
      'time.php',
      $('#order_form').serialize(),
      function(msg){
        $('#order_time').html(msg);
        });
      return false;
  });
```

Как получить обработанные данные в виде структурированных данных (например массива). Дело в том, что эти данные необходимо обновлять в таблице, которая генерируется процедурно.

Comment: Скажу глупость, наверное, но как отправите результаты работы в time.php, такими они и будут получены в яваскрипт-сценарии. Если time.php возвратит массив, то и получите массив.

Comment: С AJAX я познакомился только сегодня едва-едва. Пока еще не освоил документацию, плохо ориентируюсь. Не могли бы вы примером направить меня на путь истинный?

Comment: @Denis I, Ничего не понятно, но очень интересно...

Comment: "С AJAX я познакомился только..." Сейчас дело не в этом. Есть желание - научитесь, дело в том, что данные вернёт php-скрипт, то есть надо иметь представление о том как в php работать с массивами.

Comment: php скрипт собирает массив нужный вам $array, затем делает вывод echo json_encode($array), т.е. выводит массив в виде JSON, далее ваш js должен распарсить JSON.parse(...) и в итоге в js у вас получается массив с котором можно делать что хотите

Comment: @ssv32 не  надо там ничего парсить на стороне js. особенно, если пхп вернул `Content-type: application/json`

Comment: @teran спасибо за наводку, позже для себя почитаю про это, обычно много данных не возвращаю типа ок или ошибка поэтому описанной конструкции хватает и проблем не вызывала

Comment: @ Vadim Pedchenko, есть исходные данные, которые через POST передаются в php-обработчик. Обработать и вернуть эти данные в массив - не проблема. Проблема в том, как этот массив вернуть обратно на страницу с формой.

Comment: непонятно в чём проблемы, было бы неплохо пример. Если вы делаете что то типа гуглл таблиц и надо возвращать в теже места данные откуда они пришли, то надо передавать что то явное в php и обратно говорящее о месте куда надо вставить данные, а далее просто раскрутить и вставить

Comment: @ssv32 Почти разобрался. Передаю данные из php-обработчика, парсю. Проблема теперь в том, что есть ассоциативный массив, откуда циклом нужно выдрать данные.

Answer (score 0):

$data = ['id' => 10 , 'name' => 'test'];
return json_encode(['status' =>true,'message' =>' все отлично!','data' => $data]);

как то так . а вот какие данные надеюсь разберешься